# Redirect stacktraces to logfile instead of console output?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

whenever I get an unhandled exception or stacktrace output in the serverconsole, I would rather be saving this to a global logfile. And *not* to print it in the server console.

How can I prevent or redirect these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not kosher on java-ee, in general, have a look at [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html).

In earlier days, you had to manage a threadgroup to intercept uncaught exceptions, but now you can [set the default handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `PrintStream` instance that is set for `System.err` via the method `System.setErr`. However, this will redirect all output sent to `System.err` to the log file.

Comment: Ok I think this will also rewrite statements like server startup events etc. these should still be present in the server terminal.

Comment: If you normally write to `System.out`, these messages will still be shown in the console/terminal. It's only error messages sent to `System.err` that will be redirected. I have corrected my answer with the correct method call.